# Leaflet draw polyline and parse geojson to create cross section profile

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geoserver

I have a grid cell shapefile being served by geoserver as JSONP using WFS.  It has 1/4 mile grid cells that contain property values for elevations of various geology layers.  I am wanting to create a cross section graph using highcharts.  I have created a map that lets the user click a single point and produces a graph for that location.

Now I am trying to allow for a polyline to be drawn using the draw plugin.  The distance along the polyline would form the x axis of the graph, and the property values of the JSON at each point would form the y axis.  I know there are plugins for elevation profile, which is essentially what I am doing, but only with my own data.  I have searched and found this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110241/how-to-get-elevation-profile-from-tif-dsm-on-the-web-map, where the OP said he used GeomUtils.js but did not go into further details.  I am fairly new to leaflet and javascript, so I need a bit more handholding.  What is available for this and how would you go about writing it?

Comment: I have looked at the leaflet plugin Leaflet.GeometryUtil http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/ and found interpolateOnLine will return the coordinate of the point located on a line at the specified ratio of the line length.  Has anybody used this before?